# Proving Maximal Derivative Bound for a Twice Continuously Differentiable Function on a Closed Interval

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

Let $f \in C^2[a,b]$ be a function, where $f(a) = f(b) = 0$. Define $M = \max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}\{|f''(x)|\}$. I am trying to show that
$$\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f'(x)| \leqslant \frac{M}{2}(b-a).$$

I have tried following process.

First we let $f(c)=\max\limits_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$ (or $f(c)=\min\limits_{x\in[a,b]}\{f(x)\}$). By using the Fermat theorem we can show that
$$
f'(c)=0.
$$

By using Taylor's formula with Lagrange remainder, we can get that for $\forall i\in[a,b]$,

$$
f'(i)=f'(c)+f''(\xi)(i-c),\qquad \text{where }\xi\in(c,i)\text{ or }(i,c)
$$

However, it is unclear how to proceed from here. Performing either summation or multiplication leads to the intermediate result

$$\max_{x\in[a,b]}|f'(x)| \leqslant M(b-a),$$
which is weaker than the desired conclusion.

I would appreciate any insights or proofs related to the inequality stated above. Any help would be valuable. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few other attempts I managed to solve this problem.

Because $f(a) = f(b) = 0$, let's take $x \in (a, b)$ and expand around $x$ at $a$ and $b$:

$$
f(a) = f(x) + f'(x)(a-x) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(a-x)^2,\\
f(b) = f(x) + f'(x)(b-x) + \frac{f''(\mu)}{2}(b-x)^2,
$$

where $\xi\in (a,x),\ \mu\in(b,x)$. Therefore,
$$
0 = f(a) - f(b) = f(x) + f'(x)(a-x) + \frac{f''(\xi)}{2}(a-x)^2 - \left(f(x) + f'(x)(b-x) + \frac{f''(\mu)}{2}(b-x)^2\right).
$$

Hence, using the triangle inequality,
$$
|f'(x)| \leq \frac{\frac{M}{2}((x-a)^2+(x-b)^2)}{b-a}.
$$
If we let $(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2=g(x)$, then it can be easily calculated that when $g'(x) = 0,\ x=\frac{a+b}{2}$. Simple calculations show that $g(\frac{a+b}{2})<g(a)=g(b)$, so the maximum is attained at either $a$ or $b$, therefore
$$
|f'(x)| \leq \frac{\frac{M}{2}((b-a)^2+(b-b)^2)}{b-a} = \frac{\frac{M}{2}g(b)}{b-a} = \frac{M}{2}(b-a).
$$

Comment: I think there is an error in your calculatoin of $g'(x)$, it is not positive everywhere. But $g$ *is* convex on $[a, b]$ so that the maximum is attained at a boundary point and your conclusion still holds.

Comment: @MartinR I checked my proof and fixed some typo. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this a correct assertion?

Here is a counterexample. Let $\alpha\in (0,1)$ be fixed and define
$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
e^x & 0\leq x\leq \alpha, \\
e^{-x} & -\alpha\leq x\leq 0.
\end{cases}
$$

Although $g(x)$ is not $C^2$ at origin, we can use the smoothing technique to get a $C^2$ function $f(x)$ based on $g(x)$. Then obviously
$$
\max_{x\in[-\alpha,\alpha]} |f’(x)| = e^\alpha\qquad \text{and} \qquad
\max_{x\in[-\alpha,\alpha]} |f’’(x)| = e^\alpha.
$$
However $e^\alpha \leq \frac{e^\alpha}{2} (\alpha - (-\alpha))$ can not hold in this case provided $\alpha\in (0,1)$.

Comment: What about the given condition $f(a) = f(b) = 0$?

Comment: Adding a constant to a function doesn’t influence all the derivatives, so we can just require $f(a)=f(b)$.

Comment: That is correct. I just wonder where the flaw in the proof in Flaming's answer is, I cannot see it yet.

Comment: I am not sure, but your “smoothing” might produce larger values of $f''$ near the origin.